# Aggregating rows based on one column with ", ".join -- TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found

Tags: python, pandas, join, aggregate, nonetype

I'm doing something like

```
dfAgg =   df.groupby('col1').agg({'col2': (", ").join, 
                                  'col3':'first',
                                  'col4': sum,
                                }).reset_index()
```

and I get

> TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found

There are None values in my col2. Is there a way to ignore those with `join`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a try with a lambda expression

```
custom_agg = lambda ar: ', '.join([item for item in ar if item])

dfAgg = df.groupby('col1').agg({'col2': custom_agg, 
                                  'col3':'first',
                                  'col4': sum,
                                }).reset_index()
```